# [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following `Navigation.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{user.first_name}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['myAccount'])
    },

    mounted: function () {
      if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
        this.myAccount()
      }
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['user'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

This code returns:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of null"
```

but the strange thing is that user first name is showing correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming this is because, in your vuex store, the state of `user` is initialized as `null`. Just initialize the `user` to an empty object `{}`.

Comment: Add Your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are most likely getting that error because `user` in your Vuex store is initially set to `null`. The `user` getter mapped to your Vue component is returning that `null` value before some initialization to the Vuex store properly sets the `user`.

You could initially set the `user` to an empty object `{}`. This way, `user.first_name` in your Vue component's template will be `undefined` and nothing will be rendered in the template.

---

Alternatively, you could add a `v-if="user"` attribute to the containing `div` element:

```
<div v-if="user">
  {{ user.first_name }}
</div>
```

This way, the `div` and its contents will not be rendered until the value of the mapped `user` property is truthy. This will prevent Vue from trying to access `user.first_name` until the `user` is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was to set the user to an empty string `' '` instead of null.

```
const state = {
    user: ''
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
beforeMount(){
 if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
        this.myAccount()
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).